# how to Rotate YuvImage in xamarin android

Tags: android, image, rotation, xamarin.forms

i am converting bytearray of image into YuvImage in android interface for my xamarin applicaion like this

```
      public KeyValuePair<string, string> CaptureImageFromBarcode(byte[] bt, int width, int height)
    {

        Java.IO.FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        Android.Graphics.YuvImage yuvimage = new Android.Graphics.YuvImage(bt, Android.Graphics.ImageFormat.Nv21, width, height,null);
        MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
        yuvimage.CompressToJpeg(new Android.Graphics.Rect(0, 0, width, height), 80, baos);
        var directory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
        string filenamefile = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg";
        string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory.AbsolutePath, filenamefile);
        outStream = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(filename);
        outStream.Write(baos.ToArray());
        outStream.Close();
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(filenamefile, filename);
    }
```

here i save image to disk .but saved image is rotated left by 90 degree.so i want to save image proper rotated by 90 degree right .i tried some code but it dont give me proper output.

this is what i tried yet.

tried code 1 :

```
private byte[] rotateYUV420Degree90(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
    {
        byte[] yuv = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2];
        // Rotate the Y luma
        int i = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = imageHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                yuv[i] = data[y * imageWidth + x];
                i++;
            }
        }
        // Rotate the U and V color components 
        i = imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2 - 1;
        for (int x = imageWidth - 1; x > 0; x = x - 2)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight / 2; y++)
            {
                yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth) + x];
                i--;
                yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth) + (x - 1)];
                i--;
            }
        }
        return yuv;
    }
```

Tried Code 2:

```
   public static byte[] rotateNV21(byte[] input, byte[] output, int width, int height, int rotation)
    {
        Boolean swap = (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270);
        Boolean yflip = (rotation == 90 || rotation == 180);
        Boolean xflip = (rotation == 270 || rotation == 180);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                int xo = x, yo = y;
                int w = width, h = height;
                int xi = xo, yi = yo;
                if (swap)
                {
                    xi = w * yo / h;
                    yi = h * xo / w;
                }
                if (yflip)
                {
                    yi = h - yi - 1;
                }
                if (xflip)
                {
                    xi = w - xi - 1;
                }
                output[w * yo + xo] = input[w * yi + xi];
                int fs = w * h;
                int qs = (fs >> 2);
                xi = (xi >> 1);
                yi = (yi >> 1);
                xo = (xo >> 1);
                yo = (yo >> 1);
                w = (w >> 1);
                h = (h >> 1);
                // adjust for interleave here
                int ui = fs + (w * yi + xi) * 2;
                int uo = fs + (w * yo + xo) * 2;
                // and here
                int vi = ui + 1;
                int vo = uo + 1;
                output[uo] = input[ui];
                output[vo] = input[vi];
               // return output;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Tried code 3:

```
 public static void rotateY12toYUV420(byte[] input, byte[] output, int width, int height, int rotation)
    {
        Boolean swap = (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270);
        Boolean flip = (rotation == 90 || rotation == 180);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {


                int xo = x, yo = y;
                int w = width, h = height;
                int xi = xo, yi = yo;
                if (swap)
                {
                    xi = w * yo / h;
                    yi = h * xo / w;
                }
                if (flip)
                {
                    xi = w - xi - 1;
                    yi = h - yi - 1;
                }
                output[w * yo + xo] = input[w * yi + xi];
                int fs = w * h;
                int qs = (fs >> 2);
                xi = (xi >> 1);
                yi = (yi >> 1);
                xo = (xo >> 1);
                yo = (yo >> 1);
                w = (w >> 1);
                int ui = fs + w * yi + xi;
                int uo = fs + w * yo + xo;
                int vi = qs + ui;
                int vo = qs + uo;
                output[uo] = input[vi];
                output[vo] = input[ui];
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried code 4:

```
        public Bitmap rotateImage(int angle, Bitmap bitmapSrc)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSrc, 0, 0,
            bitmapSrc.getWidth(), bitmapSrc.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

please help.
Thank you.

Comment: why u want to do that. you can capture jpeg with rotation than convert into YUV. if it works than it is easy way

Comment: actually here image (byte[] bt) i am getting is not from camera.that i am getting from barcode scanner dll result. so it is by default rotated.

Comment: okay, which lib you using for barcode scanning. that library not provide rotation feature ?

Comment: zxing.net.moobile lib m using for scanning

Comment: no...why???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Android.Graphics.Bitmap bmp = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            Android.Graphics.Matrix matrix = new Android.Graphics.Matrix();
            matrix.PostRotate(90);
            bmp = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, matrix, true);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, ms.ToArray());
```

this code worked for me.

Comment: Accept answer :https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1):

please check out this

https://blog.xamarin.com/barcode-scanning-made-easy-with-zxing-net-for-xamarin-forms/

This provide support for rotation.

I hope this will help you.